# How do i make sure the Menu Item is always on the topbar?

Tags: android

[image: Menuitem]

the 2 menu item `connect` and `disconnect` coded such that only 1 of them shows at a time. 
I want to make it on the top bar, and not under the `...` button.

following is my menu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
    android:checkable="false"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_connect"
    android:icon="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/menu_connect"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_disconnect"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:title="@string/menu_disconnect"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting...

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

... in the item you want to be shown in the top bar (app bar) **always**?

**EDIT:**

or...

```
app:showAsAction="always|withText"
```

if yout want to show the title too.

Comment: Which screen size are you working on? 

If small, have you check there is enough space... For example try with one item at time.

Comment: i coded it such that only 1 of the 2 menuitems will be visible at a time. so there should only ever be 1. hmm.. after trying the `app:showAsAction="always|withText"` again, it somehow worked, even tho im pretty sure ive tried the same thing just now and doesnt... one of the "my code doesnt work and i dont know why. my code works and i dont know why." moments. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
    android:checkable="false"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_connect"
    android:icon="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/menu_connect"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_disconnect"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:title="@string/menu_disconnect"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

I hope it will help your problem!

Answer (score 1):

If you still have same problem even you set `app:showAsAction="always"`, you should check `onCreateOptionsMenu`. Please try this if you're creating menu differently, it will help you.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gatt_services, menu);` should work the same right? `gatt_services` is the menu

Comment: yeap. normally someone missed this.